# How to receive multiple binary values in one AJAX response?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, binaryfiles

The goal is to send a list of items to retrieve from the server, which queries the file system or a database and ideally returns an array of binary files.

My current methodology is to base64 encode binaries into a JSON array.

```
// Extend Array class methods to NodeList data type
Object.getOwnPropertyNames( Array.prototype ).forEach( function(method){
  if (method !== 'length')
    NodeList.prototype[method]=Array.prototype[method];
});

// Find People
var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('div.people');
var people   = nodeList.map(function(el){ return el.dataset.personid; });

// Search Server
var request    = new XMLHttpRequest();
var skip_cache = '?' + new Date().getTime();
request.open('POST', 'cgi.script' + skip_cache );
request.responseType = 'json';
request.onload = function(){
  // response handler
  /* receives json from server, including an array of base64 files for each person 
     loop over array and append base64 values to images (data uri) and prepare other HTML elements 
  */
};
request.send( JSON.stringify({ids:people}) );
```

The bottleneck is the size of the request - I'm already breaking the number of people into multiple requests.  Although, base64 is only ~37% larger in its uncompressed state; when you have 1k files to download, it doesn't matter.

The goal is to reduce the size per request (without sacrificing time), which has come down to either a better compression method (lzma vs gzip), or improving the data format (binary over ascii).

Is it possible to transfer multiple binary files at once, or even embed them directly in JSON without side-effects? As a preventative measure I've never attempted this, thinking of possible side effects that would challenge technology of yesteryear.

Comment: Would issuing multipart requests solve your issue?

Comment: @kazenorin I've only ever used multipart when attaching files to email, or posting data to the server; never when receiving files from the server.  Is that common?  If so, then I suppose that yes it may be what I need.  I just want to transfer multiple binaries in the same message, without being overly clever (packing an octet string, or custom tar/zip).

Comment: @kazenorin I saw this: http://test.getify.com/mpAjax/description.html, which is just trying to be clever about formatting a string with the headers and parsing as necessary.  That wouldn't be any more useful than a good JSON schema.  To that effect, it doesn't look like it handles binary data.

Comment: No need for multipart - it's not greatly supported, you still have the encoding issue... Rather, just do a pure [binary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data) protocol. For example, send number of files, then length of filename, filename, length of file, file for each file.

Comment: @Amadan do you know if there are any examples?  I've been inquiring about the ArrayBuffer recently, but haven't seen any more advanced examples.  I assume what you're suggesting is to use two different requests: (1) request metadata (2) pack the buffer on the server with all the files; and in the client, splice the buffer using the metadata.

Comment: You can have metadata in the same request. However, your question is too vague for me to offer any more details. What will you do with the binary data on the client once they arrive? Display them as images? Allow user to download? Unpack and show a data collection that is packed inside as form elements?...

Comment: @Amadan yes :) a mixture of those; images displayed.  PDF,XLS,Docs... etc as an html element that holds it's value in the data-* attributes (I'm thinking), or held in localStorage until needed.  That's why my response handler is not filled in above.  Right now it's using data URI for setting image src; but I'd rather escape that and set the binary directly.  So let's go under the assumption that there are  1000-5000 images being sent from the server in batches of ~20 images per HTTP request.  I think if I do binary I can make that ~30 images per request.

Comment: I'd imagine displaying 1k PDF/XLS/... files to the user at the same time is somewhat of a challenge, whatever you choose to do... :P

Comment: There's expectation setting to users, but I've tuned my algorithm based on connection speed, size of files, etc. and it's reasonably responsive (for me not being an expert in media file transfers).  Deciding that caching should be avoided was especially helpful. but I think getting that extra little bit would be a big win.